# Importing Table From Another Database Creating New Table Rather Than Append Data Into Existing Table

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am trying to import all data from a table of database to existing table in local database. But it creating new table rather than copying data into table. I am using following simple code for testing. So, how can I import data instead of creating new table? Please Note:

> Both `tables` data structure are same.
>   Table has a `Primary Key` Field.

```
Private Sub cmdRestore_Click()
    DoCmd.TransferDatabase acImport, "Microsoft Access", "C:\Users\Harun.Rashid\Documents\DestinationDB.accdb", acTable, "tblEmpData", "tblEmpData"
End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell, that is the way TransferDatabase is supposed to work. It is not intended to be a repetitive process. Alternative options:

1. set a link and use the linked table as source for subsequent SELECT queries - don't even need to populate a local table but if you insist then use the link as source for APPEND or UPDATE actions
2. use Execute method that directly references other database file path in an INSERT SELECT action, like:
   `CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO tblEmpData SELECT * FROM tblEmpData IN 'C:\Users\Harun.Rashid\Documents\DestinationDB.accdb'"`

Comment: I will check and feedback to you.

Answer (score 1):

*Link* the backup table and then run an *append query* using the linked tabled as source and the local table as destination.

Comment: Yes. I can do that but I was trying automate it through single click.

Comment: Sure. Your "single click" should call a function that links the table, executes the append query, then deletes the linked table.

Comment: No. Access is single-threaded, so while your function runs you should show the hourglass to tell the user, that Access is working on the import.

Comment: How can I use `hourglass`? I am not familiar with `hourglass`.

Comment: `DoCmd.Hourglass True|False`.

Comment: I did few google search and read articles. Clear about `Hourglass`. Thanks.